# Apache starts with "Syntax error on /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf: Invalid command 'remove'"

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, centos, php

After I changed `php.ini` max file upload size and the max post size, restarting apache shows the error in the title. Why? And how to resolve it?

```
# vi /etc/php.ini
# service httpd restart


# service httpd start
Starting httpd: Syntax error on line 304 of /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf:
Invalid command 'remove', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration
```

The line 304 follows:

```
<Directory />
    Options Includes Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    remove word Indexes
    Options Includes FollowSymlinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride None
</Directory>
```

Comment: check line number 304 on ``/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf` file. Maybe some typo there

Answer (score 4, accepted):

del line 3 and 4 on that snippet. Your config should looks like this

```
<Directory />
    Options Includes Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride None
</Directory>
```

Comment: Thanks! it works. what's different between Options FollowSymLinks  and   Options Includes Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews ??

Comment: You should refers to [official documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#options)